# What does the icon before Local Branches mean in Android Studio 3.3.1?

Tags: git, android-studio

I find that there are two icons before both *newCW* and *master* Local Branches, what does these icon mean?

And more, none icon before other Local Branches such as *MyNewbrach2*, *MyNewBranch*, why?

**Image**
[image]

Comment: On left of newCW is it a tag ?
Star - is current branch ?

Comment: I thing one of those icons (newCW?) means the current branch and the other means the default branch (the star?). It's just a guess though.

Comment: @HelloCW So I gues you don't have any tags there ? I mean more like newCW is a branch with a TAG on its HEAD.

Comment: I havn't added any tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The star icon next to the `master` branch means that it is marked as a favorite branch. This is a default behavior from IntelliJ. ([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-branches.html))

The icon next to the `newCW` is the HEAD icon. It means that this is the branch you are working on.
I haven't found an explicit description of this in the docs, but you can see it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html). It's almost the same icon for tags, just not the same color ([see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/use-tags-to-mark-specific-commits.html)).

Because Android Studio is built on top of IntelliJ, don't hesitate to look at [IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/) for IDE relative questions.